# Is a TileService considered as foreground process

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding, android-8.0-oreo

In Android O we have some new [background limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html). For example we can only register implicit broadcasts via the `Context.registerReceiver` method. When the system kills our process (e.g. as a result of low memory) the registered receivers will also be destroyed.

To reduce the chance that the system kills our process we have to tell the system that this process is still in the foreground. As per [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#services) an app is considered to be in the foreground if any of the following is true:

> - It has a visible activity, whether the activity is started or paused.
> - It has a foreground service
> - Another foreground app is connected to the app, either by binding to one of its services or by making use of one of its content providers. For example, the app is in the foreground if another app binds to its:
>
>   1. IME
>   2. Wallpaper service
>   3. Notification listener
>   4. Voice or text service

If none of those conditions is true, the app is considered to be in the background.

What about `TileService` (for quick setting tiles) which were introduced in Android N? When we register a `TileService` as `ACTIVE_TILE` in the mainfest file the system does not bind the service every time the tile becomes visible (as noted in this [article](https://medium.com/google-developers/quick-settings-tiles-e3c22daf93a8)) and therefore our service is bind to another application, in face the system process.

So is my application (as long as the tile is added to the quick settings pane) considered as foreground application? This would be nice because I do not need a persistent notification with this approach and it is nevertheless possible for the user to send my app in the background (by removing the tile)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So is my application (as long as the tile is added to the quick settings pane) considered as foreground application?

Not normally. Quoting the article that you linked to:

> It is important to note that your `TileService` will mostly certainly be unbound (and destroyed) when the user is not viewing the tile — don’t assume that your Service will be alive outside of the `onStartListening()`/`onStopListening()` pair of methods.

So, most of the time, your service will be unbound and destroyed.

---

> the system does not bind the service every time the tile becomes visible (as noted in this article)

My guess is that you are referring to these paragraphs:

> In active mode, your `TileService` will still be bound for `onTileAdded()` and `onTileRemoved()` (and for click events). However, the only time you’ll get a callback to `onStartListening()` is after you call the static `TileService.requestListeningState()` method. You’ll then be able to update your tile exactly once before receiving a callback to `onStopListening()`. This gives you an easy one-shot ability to update your tile right when your data changes whether the tile is visible or not.
>
> Since active tiles don’t have to be bound every time the tile becomes visible, active tiles are better for system health. Building active tiles means less processes the system needs to bind to every time the quick settings panel becomes visible. (Of course, the system already limits the amount of bound `TileServices` based on available memory, etc, but by then you’re already near the border of memory thrashing — not where you want to be.)

I would expect there to be some sort of timeout mechanism: if you call `requestListeningState()`, then do not update the tile within X seconds, you will be called with `onStopListening()`. The listening state is not durable; it only lives for one update. So, the system should be expecting an update in a timely fashion. I will test this scenario and will file a bug report if a `TileService` can be indefinitely bound this way, as that's a waste of system resources.

Comment: What would be the advantage of using a `TileService` over a Foreground Service?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: They are not really related. `TileService` is for displaying a tile in the notification shade, and I would not expect it to be a foreground service normally (as then you have a notification and would not need a tile).

Comment: Actually, one advantage of TileService I've discovered is that it automatically starts when the device starts.  We cannot do that with foreground services.  Only WorkManager can do that.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: "We cannot do that with foreground services" -- you can use an `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` receiver to start the foreground service.

Comment: This behaviour seems weird if you decide to show a dialog from your quick setting which is a part of the API. The service can be destroyed while the dialog is still on screen so you need to be very careful what happens when the user interacts with the dialog.

Comment: @tom-pratt: Last I checked, a `Service` cannot display a `Dialog`. It could launch a dialog-themed `Activity`. If the `Activity` needs to interact with the `Service` for one reason or another, it should bind to that `Service`, to prevent the `Service` from being destroyed. It's possible there are some restrictions that prevent this, but I cannot think of any off the top of my head.

Comment: @CommonsWare It is specific to TileService. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/quicksettings/TileService#showDialog(android.app.Dialog)